# How to process identical rows on Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I'm starting using Spring Batch and I would like help how to solve the problem below:

My first job the result of .reader is

PersonA   ImageA Priority1

PersonA   ImageB Priority2

PersonA   ImageC Priority3

In .processor I must process the image and send it to AWS S3.
If the process to send ImageA to S3 returns OK, I must not process other images (B and C),
but If the process to send ImageA to S3 returns an error, I must process ImageB and if ImageB is neither ok, must process ImageC.

How can I do this if the .processor supposedly executes 1 line at a time ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Can you put together a test to verify functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to do that with a single chunk-oriented step in a *clean* way. How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? If you share a solution (an algorithm), I can try to help you implement it in a (multi-step) Spring Batch job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the step `ExecutionContext`, in which you can store some (lightweight) data, so you can use it to "remember" if an image has already been successfully processed before processing another one.

Make your processor implement the `StepExecutionListener` interface, in order to retrieve the `StepExecution` from the `beforeStep()` method. Then you can access the `ExecutionContext` via `StepExecution.getExecutionContext()` which has some methods such as `put(key, value)`, `get(key)` and so on.

Here is an example of implementation:

```java
class MyProcessor extends ItemProcessor<Input, Output> implements StepExecutionListener {

    private static final String KEY_IS_IMAGE_PROCESSED = "MyProcessor.isImageProcessed";
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    Output process(Input item) {
        // Skip item if a previous image has already been successfully processed
        if(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey(KEY_IS_IMAGE_PROCESSED) {
            return null;
        }

        Output output = null;
        try {
            // Process image
            output = doProcess(item);
            // If successful, remember image has been processed in order to skip next ones
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put(KEY_IS_IMAGE_PROCESSED, true);
        } // If unsuccessful, will return null (skipping write) and process next image
        catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }

    ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

NB: if your reader reads a lot of items and your step is chunk-oriented, you can also make it implement `StepExecutionListener` the same way, to stop reading items once an image has been successfully processed in a previous chunk.